# Upload batch of files to YouTube with 'private' publishing setting

Tags: youtube, upload

[image]

When uploading a batch of files to YouTube, the 'privacy and publishing' setting is set to 'public'. I want my batch to be 'private'.

Is there a way to do this for all files in a sort of single step so that I do not have to edit the setting from the default of 'public' to 'private' for *all* the files in the batch?

Answer (score 1):

I remember using it long time ago:

- [Free Youtube Uploader](http://www.dvdvideosoft.com/products/dvd/Free-YouTube-Uploader.htm)

It gives you the option to set every video public/private before starting the upload. Give it a try.